# pdflatex and filenames with spaces in java

Tags: java, filenames, pdflatex

I am trying to pass filenames with spaces to pdflatex inside a java application using Runtime.exec().

This command executes well on the terminal

```
pdflatex --halt-on-error "/home/jody/test 1.tex"
```

i.e. a pdf is generated, and the return code is 0.

The same command will not work (i.e. return code 1 instead of 0; no pdf created) when passed to exec() like this

```
myRuntime.exec("pdflatex --halt-on-error \"/home/jody/test 1.tex\"", null, null);
```

How do i have to write such a command to get it to work?
Thanks
   Jody

Comment: Have you checked to make sure your code works for filenames without spaces?

Comment: yes, file names without spaces work, both "naked" or enclosed in quotes

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

Instead of using

```
public Process exec(String command,
                    String[] envp,
                    File dir)
```

where the entire call is contained in the string 'command',
i now use

```
public Process exec(String[] cmdarray,
                    String[] envp,
                    File dir)
```

where the call is split up into an array 'cmdarray' containing the command (i.e. "pdflatex") and its arguments as elements. That way pdflatex understands the space-infested file name as single word, and can complete its job.